# SwiftUI Button Disable styling does not work in some cases

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the following button in a custom view that I reuse in multiple places

```
                    Button(action: { selectedDate = date }) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(day.shortName)
                            .font(.caption2)
                            .foregroundColor(isSelectedDate ? .white : .primary)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 7)
                        
                        Text("\(date.dayOfMonth)")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(isSelectedDate ? .white : .primary)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.purple.brightness(isSelectedDate ? 0 : 0.6))
                    .clipped()
                }.disabled(isInPast)
```

Dates in the past supposed to be disabled, and I confirmed that they are actually disabled as expected; however, the disabled styling looks different in multiple screens although it's the exact same view being used.

What could cause the disable state to not be styled accordingly in some screens?

In both screenshots dates from 25-29 are disabled

[image]

[image]

In both usages I simply add the view to a VStack

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        WeekView(selectedDate: $booking.selectedDate).padding()

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        WeekView(selectedDate: $selectedDate)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the parent in one of the screens had `.buttonStyle(.plain)` which makes the disabled styling work as expected. So I just dded that to the component itself to make sure the disabled styling is always in place

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on `primary` color. Use a custom color and use `isInPast` to make an opacity.

Comment: I really rather know what's going on because even if i set the color manually, one view which takes the disabled styling will be styled differently, including the background color